# Reducing a boolean expression with nested ternary expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Consider the following boolean expression with a nested ternary expression:

$$(\text{if $a < 0$ then $-a$ else $a$}) < 3$$

I can "see" that it can be reduced to:

$$a > -3 \land a < 3$$

However, I can't figure out the algebraic rules I need to apply in order to arrive at the reduced expression.

I got as far as:

$$(\text{if $a < 0$ then $-a$ else $a$}) < 3$$
$$\text{if $a < 0$ then $-a < 3$ else $a < 3$}$$
$$\text{if $a < 0$ then $a > -3$ else $a < 3$}$$
$$(a < 0 \land a > -3) \lor (\lnot(a < 0) \land a < 3)$$
$$(a < 0 \land a > -3) \lor (a \ge 0 \land a < 3)$$

But that's where I'm stuck. I think somewhere in between I should arrive at:

$$(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0) \lor (a > -3 \land a < 3)$$

Or maybe:

$$(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0) \land (a > -3 \land a < 3)$$

Because then the term $(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0)$ would cancel out. So I tried my way backwards from there, but I still no luck.

I feel like I'm missing something quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

From:

$$(a < 0 \land a > -3) \lor (a \ge 0 \land a < 3)$$

Distribute (FOIL, basically):

$$(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0) \land  (a < 0 \lor a < 3) \land (a > -3 \lor a < 3) \land  (a > -3 \lor a \ge 0)$$

Now, as you say, $(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0)$ is a mathetical truth, and so can be ignored:

$$ (a < 0 \lor a < 3) \land (a > -3 \lor a < 3) \land  (a > -3 \lor a \ge 0)$$

Also, since $a < 0$ implies $a<3$, the term $(a < 0 \lor a < 3)$ reduces to the weakest claim, i.e. to $a < 3$. Likewise, $(a > -3 \lor a \ge 0)$ reduces to $a > -3$:

$$ a < 3 \land (a > -3 \lor a < 3) \land  a > -3 $$

Finally, if $a < 3$ and $a > -3$, then certainly  $(a > -3 \lor a < 3)$, so that middle term can be completely removed, leaving you with:

$$ a < 3 \land  a > -3 $$

Now, note that this transformation was not a purely *logical* transformation, but that is because the equivalence between your original statement and the statement $ a < 3 \land  a > -3 $ is indeed 'merely' a *mathematical* equivalence, and not a logical one. For, example, $(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0)$ is a *mathematical* truth, and not a *logical* one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Your point about logical vs mathematical truth seems interesting. Do you have some pointers where I could read up on that?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride No pointers, really. Just remember that in logic, only the purely logical operators, like $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$, or $\forall$ have a fixed meaning. A mathematical relationship, like $<$, however, is in the eyes of logic 'just some 2-place relationship'. And even the constant $0$ is 'just some object from some domain'

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
(a < 0 \land a > -3) \lor (a \ge 0 \land a < 3) \\
(a < 0 \lor a \ge 0) \land (a < 0 \lor a < 3) \land (a > -3 \lor a \ge 0) \land (a > -3 \lor a < 3) \\
1 \land (a < 3) \land (a > -3) \land 1 \\
(a < 3) \land (a > -3)
\end{equation}

Comment: @Bram28 $a > -3 \vee a < 3$ is indeed true of all real numbers.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Wow, brain fart! :P